# Saving / Loading HashMap<String, Integer> into file.txt

Tags: java, bukkit

I would love to know how can I save and load my **HashMap** from a file called **data.txt** , I'm already using a method to save and load the HashMap from a **config.yml** *(which i will show you below)*.

Here is my HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Integer> points = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

This is my saving method for the HashMap from the config.yml

```
public void savePoints(){
    for (Entry<String, Integer> pointstostore : points.entrySet()) {
        getConfig().set(pointstostore.getKey(), pointstostore.getValue());
    }
    saveConfig();
}
```

This is my loading method for the HashMap from the config.yml

```
public void loadPoints(){
    for (String str : getConfig().getKeys(true)) {
        int p = getConfig().getInt(str);
        points.put(str, p);
    }
}
```

The config.yml is structured like that in a yaml format

```
playername: points
playername2: points
...
```

Is there any way for me to create a new file called **data.txt** from which I can save and load the HashMap points for every player and request from each player the amount of points they have and the file to have the following or a similar format

```
players:
   points:
      playername: points
      playername2: points
      ...
```

Comment: Hashmaps play nicely with JSON format... Though, you havent specified how the text file should even look, which is very important if you want to read the file back into a Map

Comment: I would just use the YAML library to do this. You can have Config inside Config.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by using a Properties.

To write:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.putAll(points):
try (FileOutputStream fos = new    FileOutputStream("file.txt");) {
    p.store(fos, null);
}
```

To read:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream("file.txt");) {
    p.load(fos);
    points = new Hasmap<>(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a new .yml file you do:

```
public class Main {

    private File datafile;
    private FileConfiguration data;

    public void onEnable() {

        datafile = new File(getDataFolder(), "data.yml");
        data = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(datafile);
        saveDataYml();

    }


    public static void saveDataYml() {

        try{
            data.save(datafile);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static FileConfiguration getDataYml() {
        return data;
    }

}
```